# Losing texture after going back to menu in Unity5 in IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, textures

I have a game, that follows this flow: SplashScreen -> Menu -> Level1 -> Menu

The first time the menu is opened, everything is fine:

[image]

After I come back from the game (I checked, and the same amount of objects are on the scene both times), this is what I get:

[image]

NOTE: This is on ios devices, both ipod touch & ipad. I'm using Unity 5.0.0p3 & NGUI 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this issue... I was having Time.timescale = 0 before loading the scene again, causing the issue.